# Overriding jQuery UI style on specific components

Tags: jquery, user-interface

As much as I like themeRoller I would like to be able to manipulate and replace the css styling of some of my jQuery UI components, especially the buttons.

I've been successful at changing the font and size but I'm unable to change the background image and padding. I looked around in the theme css file in the hopes of finding something to overwrite, but nothing seemed to work.

Can someone give me some insight on how to get the achieve the code below correctly?:P

**.CSS file**

```
#create-user .ui-button
{
    background-image: none;
}
```

**.xhtml file**

```
<button id="create-user">Create</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following to force it:

```
#create-user .ui-button
{
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

It might also be a better idea to manually edit the original CSS file generated by themeroller.

You can also try removing some classes after you called `.button()`. The button's appearance is largely controlled by `ui-state-default` and `ui-corner-all`. Try removing those, see if your custom class starts working. It also adds `ui-state-hover` and maybe `ui-state-active` dynamically.

All in all, it's probably easier not to use a jQuery UI button, if it's just a few special cases, try styling it yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried !important earlier and it didn't work. I would also like to keep the original CSS files generated intact as this is a rare case where I want to use custom styles.

Comment: There are already some `!important` rules in the original CSS filed, might be conflicting with that.

Comment: I edited my answer, i do think it's better to style it yourself and add the jQuery UI classes that you might need manually.

Comment: Your right, it was easier and better to not use the jQuery UI button instead of trying to completely change it.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

Create a new class. Don't edit present class it may be used elsewhere also. Best way is to      create a new class:

```
.button_style{
  background:none !important;
  padding:5px !important;
 }
```

Make modification in css. Use css hack '!important'.

Comment: That worked wonders! Although there are still some functions left from jQuery such as highlight on select. Would you know of a way to also remove those?