# JQuery selectmenu how to style some options differently

Tags: jquery

Probably a simple one guys but I'm really struggling with it. Would really appreciate some help or advice if anyone can offer it, thanks.

I'm using JQuery selectmenu and all I would like to do is set a different style for any OPTION that has a particular class. The class is "outofstock", so my code is as follows;

```
<select name="dd1" id="dd1">
    <option value="1">item 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="outOfStock">item 2</option>
    <option value="3">item 3</option>
</select>
```

I would just like the second option that has class="outOfStock", to be styled with a different text or BG colour.

I have tried many (many, MANY) variations on this but just cannot get anything to work.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-selectmenu-menu-item .outOfStock{background:red;}
</style>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, some of which worked partially, however this seems to do a consistent job across different browsers AND also covers the item in its SELECTED state

```
.ui-selectmenu-menu .outOfStock{background:red;} /* item in the list */
.outOfStock .ui-selectmenu-status{background:red;color:#333}  /* item when selected */
```

This tip might help someone trying to find .ui styles...
It took me AGES to work out which .ui styles were involved during various menu states (open, hover, selected) - in the end I realised all I had to do was open Chrome (or Firefox), set Firebug going, right click my element (in this case my select-menu item) and choose "inspect Element". Firebug then showed me all the styles as they came in to play. I could then clearly see the styles change as the menu item was in its various states, hover, selected etc. Once you know the styles/classes to target, the rest is easy..hope this helps someone else. Firebug to the rescue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it is pretty much simple:

```
  $('.outOfStock').css('color','#454545');
```

And instead of using

```
  <style type="text/css"></style>
```

you should use

```
 <script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

since you want to run jQuery and not css styles.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there. Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .outOfStock {
         background-color: red !important; // changed following comments
    }
</style>
```

Use !important sparingly. More info [here](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Thanks, Ordinarily that would work on an element, but the selectmenu css does not seem to allow that class to be changed in that way. This is why I've been trying to overide/access the relevent classes i.e. .ui-selectmenu-menu-item .outOfStock{background:red;}. There are a bunch of classes that covers focus, menu-open etc and these are the ones I'm trying to overide

Comment: Thank you again, sadly I've already been down that line of thinking and it doesn't work. It's always overridden by the .ui styles, so I'm convinced that it's these classes that need targetting. I will go through each one again and see if I can work it out - thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880632/overriding-jquery-ui-style-on-specific-components), similar answer. Please post a fiddle of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is almost spectacularly useless at styling `select`, and their descendant `option`, elements, as they're typically rendered by the OS/platform, not the browser itself.

You could, though, use the `disabled` property to distinguish them:

```
$('option.outOfStock').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for but in the worst case scenario you can always go with inline styling as that will work smoothly on the select tag...

```
  <select name="dd1" id="dd1">
    <option value="1">item 1</option>
    <option value="2" style="background:red;">item 2</option>
    <option value="3">item 3</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks but inline styles get overridden by the select-menu classes (and UI widget classes). So do other standard styles, which is why they need to inlcude .ui classes to work fully. Also, inline styling does not work cross browser - thank for taking the time to offer help though!